# How do I change a label so that the text which is shown is reliant on a variable

Tags: c#, label

How do I change a label so that the text which is shown is reliant on a variable from another method?
For example I want something like
string playerOne = "Player",
computerOne = "Computer";

and have an outside variable from a method
if variable = 0 change label to show playerOne
if variable = 1 change label to show computerOne

how exactly would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: winforms or wpf,you probably need to use DataBinding

Comment: Do you want to have the text on the label automatically update when the variable changes or just to tell the label text to change?